# PIVOT in Oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, pivot

I have written a query as shown below

```
    SELECT DISTINCT SBPC1.BATCH_ID AS BATCH_ID,
  Sbpc1.Registration_Id        AS Registration_Id,
  Submtd_Val_Code.Submtd_Val_Cd,
  Submtd_Val_Code.Submtd_Val_Amount ,
  Submtd_Val_Code.Submtd_Bill_Processing_Cd_Seq
  --Submtd_Val_Code.rownumber
  --rownum
FROM TEMPORARY_EXTRACT_BASE PARTITION (TEMPORARY_EXTRACT_BA_815771) TEB,
  Submtd_Bill_Processing_Cd Sbpc1 ,
  (SELECT Sbpc1.Batch_Id  AS Batch_Id,
    Sbpc1.Registration_Id AS Registration_Id,
    Submtd_Val_Cd,
    SBPC1.SUBMTD_VAL_AMOUNT,
    Sbpc1.Submtd_Bill_Processing_Cd_Seq,
    rownum AS rownumber
  FROM Temporary_Extract_Base Partition (Temporary_Extract_Ba_815771) Teb,
    Submtd_Bill_Processing_Cd Sbpc1
  WHERE SBPC1.BATCH_ID     = TEB.EXTRACT_BATCH_ID
  AND SBPC1.REGISTRATION_ID=TEB.REGISTRATION_ID
  AND TEB.BATCH_ID         = 815771
  AND SBPC1.BATCH_ID      IN
    (SELECT BATCH_ID
    FROM PBLSH_BATCH_INCLUSION
    WHERE DATA_PBLSH_ID IN
      (SELECT DATA_PBLSH_ID FROM Batch WHERE Batch_Id = 815771
      )
    )
  AND Upper(Sbpc1.Submtd_Val_Cd) <> 'NOT AVAILABLE'
  AND Upper(Sbpc1.Submtd_Val_Cd) <> 'NOT SUPPLIED'
  ORDER BY TEB.REGISTRATION_ID,
    Sbpc1.SUBMTD_BILL_PROCESSING_CD_SEQ
  )Submtd_Val_Code
WHERE SBPC1.BATCH_ID     = TEB.EXTRACT_BATCH_ID
AND SBPC1.REGISTRATION_ID=TEB.REGISTRATION_ID
AND TEB.BATCH_ID         = 815771
AND SBPC1.BATCH_ID      IN
  (SELECT BATCH_ID
  FROM PBLSH_BATCH_INCLUSION
  WHERE DATA_PBLSH_ID IN
    (SELECT DATA_PBLSH_ID FROM BATCH WHERE Batch_Id = 815771
    )
  )
AND Submtd_Val_Code.Registration_Id =Teb.Registration_Id
ORDER BY SBPC1.BATCH_ID,
  SBPC1.REGISTRATION_ID,
  Submtd_Val_Code.SUBMTD_BILL_PROCESSING_CD_SEQ;
```

Its producing the output as:

[image]

I need the output as below, for each and every Registration_id:

[image]

The top 5 valid values should be loaded to the corresponding column. It will be better if its achieved through a single select statement without using stored procedure.

Anybody please help out... Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

Pivot can be used only if there are any aggregate functions in your selected list of values:

Example of using pivot is something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT product_code, quantity
        FROM   pivot_test)
PIVOT  (SUM(quantity) AS sum_quantity FOR (product_code) IN ('A' AS a, 'B' AS b, 'C' AS c));
```

if you can have one aggregate function, then you can try making the entire select statement as a cte (common table expression) and then use that table with the pivot method.

example:

```
with cte as 
(----- your sql statement--- )
select * from cte
pivot (sum(val) for name in ( select name from cte ) );
```

Comment: yes, pivot is used for this purpose only.

you can try as following:
`code`
with cte as (
SELECT DISTINCT SBPC1.BATCH_ID AS BATCH_ID,
  Sbpc1.Registration_Id        AS Registration_Id,
  Submtd_Val_Code.Submtd_Val_Cd,
  Submtd_Val_Code.Submtd_Val_Amount ,
  Submtd_Val_Code.Submtd_Bill_Processing_Cd_Seq
  ---- your total query---  )
  select * from cte 
  pivot (sum(Registration_Id) for Registration_Id in (46057007,46057008,....)) `code`